# How to set the default browser in KDE?

Tags: kde, konsole, defaults

*2021 update:* the unexpected behavior described below was actual in KDE Plasma v5.18.5, but isn't actual in 5.22.3 anymore.

*2023 update:* See also [this pull request in KDE's GitLab](https://invent.kde.org/plasma/plasma-workspace/-/merge_requests/3324) for some details about default browser selection in Plasma 6 ([source](https://pointieststick.com/2023/11/17/this-week-in-kde-panel-intellihide-and-wayland-presentation-time/)).

---

Linux has many ways of "marking" an application "as a default". You can check some of them using following commands:

1. `xdg-settings get default-web-browser`
2. `ls -o /etc/alternatives/*browser*`
3. `ls -o /usr/bin/*browser*` (some of these are symbolic links to the previous list item)
4. `xdg-mime query default x-scheme-handler/https`
5. `grep -E 'https|html' /etc/mailcap`
6. If you're on KDE `grep BrowserApplication ~/.kde/share/config/kdeglobals`

I'm having the exact same issue as in question [How do I change the default browser that konsole opens URLs with?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62182).

I'm running KDE 5.13.5. I did following steps:

1. Uninstall Chromium
2. Make sure all items listed above point to Firefox.
3. Go to "System Settings > Applications > Default Applications > Web Browser" (aka `$ kcmshell5 componentchooser`)
4. Change setting 'Open **http** and **https** URLs' to "in an application based on the contents of the URL"
5. Click an https link in Konsole
6. Install Chromium
7. Click an https link in Konsole

*Actual result*: after step 5, link is opened in Firefox; after step 7—in Chromium.

*Expected result*: link is opened in Firefox both in step 5 and in step 7.

So KDE decided, that this particular URL ([this one](https://www.linux-apps.com/content/show.php/Redshift+Control?content=170746)) is better suited (see step 4) for Chromium than for Firefox, despite my efforts to mark Firefox as the default browser in six different ways. If in step 4 I choose "in the following application > Firefox", then everything works as expected, but I want to have it set to "in an application based on the contents of the URL".

Which method of marking a browser as default did I miss? How do I convince KDE that this URL is better suited for Firefox, which I tried to mark as my default browser?

P.S. [This Debian bugs mail list thread](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=800502) suggests that Konsole does the same as `xdg-open <url>`, but for me clicking on URL in Konsole opens Chromium, while `xdg-open` opens Firefox.

Comment: Shot in the dark, but have you tried `.config/mimeapps.list` - https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/XDG_MIME_Applications?

Comment: @knezi Firefox has already been set up for http and https there. Now, nine months later on KDE Plasma 5.16.5 I cannot reproduce the issue.

Comment: I can reproduce this issue in KDE Plasma v5.18.5 in Kubuntu v20.04.2 LTS.

Comment: @DanielLe I can't reproduce in KDE Plasma 5.22.3 (distribution KDE Neon version 5.22). If it had been a bug in Konsole or some other KDE component, then it was fixed. Also the setting "Open http and https URLs" doesn't seem to exist anymore.

Comment: My issue was that my default browser was set, but when I clicked on an html file, another browser opened. Had to go into settings > applications > file associations to correct the issue. It's very annoying how these things are configured in KDE.

Answer (score 3):

If you right-click the link and click "save as" then select it wherever you downloaded it, click "open with" and select firefox. there should be a checkbox saying "Remember application association for all files of type "HTML document" (text/html)"

I'm not sure if this will work in the way you need, but it worked for me

Comment: It seems that you are talking about a right-click menu on a link in a web browser. The question is about links inside the program called Konsole, which isn't a web browser. P.S. please read the 2021 update at the top of the question.

Comment: In KDE this is actually the only suggestion that worked for handling the panel shortcuts.

Comment: And in case someone wants a way from terminal: `gio mime x-scheme-handler/https` to list handlers and e.g. `gio mime x-scheme-handler/https org.qutebrowser.qutebrowser.desktop` to change the handler.